# source (command) a bash script that sets FOO does not make it visible to other bash scripts

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following bash script (named "env.bash") to be consumed by the source command:

```
#!/bin/bash
FOO=/some/path
```

Then I have the following bash script (named "compile.bash"):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$FOO" ]; then
    echo "Need to set FOO, did you forget to source env.bash?"
    exit 1
fi 
./compile-something
```

However, if I do:

```
source env.bash
./compile.bash
```

I get "Need to set FOO", why? If I echo $FOO I can see its value just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
export FOO=/some/path
```

This should work. The reason is that a shell script will run in a sub-shell, which has its own copy of the environment; the variables of the super-shell are not normally visible. When you perform an `export`, you will make the copies of the exported variables available to sub-shells.

EDIT: Removed inaccuracies; also, thanks @DonCallisto for a good point.

Comment: All good but you forget about a point: when you `export` you'll make a copy into the sub-shell. So, is like define again the variable. But this isn't a "global" variable since is a copy ..